# DartEditor M4 pub functions is broken

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

Just updated to DartEditor M4 and somehow 'Pub' related functions just stop working :( :(

```
Dart Editor version 0.4.7_r21548
Dart SDK version 0.4.7.1_r21548
Linux alex 3.5.0-27-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 19:58:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I was used to right-click on `pubspec.yaml` file and choose 'Pub update' but now it just bark at me with error:

```
Please select a pubspec.yaml before running pub.
```

[image: Error screenshot]

The same error (?) I get if I click on `Tools > Pub update` and even if I double click on `pubspec.yaml` I see the window on screen it still says 'Please select...'

Is there something wrong in my Dart Editor ? Should I re-install it ?

---

## Update

---

It was fixed in:

```
    Dart Editor version 0.4.7_r21658
    Dart SDK version 0.4.7.5_r21658
```

---

Comment: You can always run the commands from the command line if the Editor is buggy, `pub update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have the same problem, 
after some discussing in the dart forum I opened the following issue:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9974&thanks=9974&ts=1366221062

Comment: So I guess it's a bug then ?

Answer (score 0):

If you did an update, do a clean install of the Editor and see if that solves the problem. I have a clean install of M4 and don't have any issues with running pub.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a clean install, you may not get the dialog with the error, but the pub tool does not actually run. Remove your packages and then try, nothing gets updated or installed.
It's badly broken.

Comment: Clean re-install of DartEditor didn't help... :( The same message appears again